# Ideal and non ideal diodes

Tags: diodes

Sorry if this question may be stupid but what's the difference between ideal and non ideal diodes? When the question says "Assume ideal diode with VD = 0.7 V" and when another says "Assume non-ideal diode with VD = 0.7 V" how will the solution differ?

(New to electronics....)

Comment: *”how will the solution differ?”* it depends on what the question is. Can you post examples?

Comment: I'm wondering why people just don't google things or read a book before asking questions.

Answer (score 2):

They are both just two different ways of saying that you don't need to worry about the variation of voltage across the diode as a function of the current through that diode. Whether or not you assume \$V_D=0\:\textrm{V}\$ or \$V_D=700\:\textrm{mV}\$, doesn't really matter. (One might be said to be "more ideal" than the other, but that's moot.)

So in one case the author is saying that the diode is not ideal in the sense that \$V_D=700\:\textrm{mV}\$ but implying that it is still ideal in the sense that \$V_D\$ doesn't vary with current (implied.) The other author is taking note of the fact that \$V_D\$ doesn't vary with current (now made explicit), so it is "ideal" in that sense, while taking note that they want you to use \$V_D=700\:\textrm{mV}\$, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

An "ideal diode model" usually assumes either

- Forward voltage is 0 V, reverse current is 0 A.

or

- Forward voltage is some fixed value (often 0.6 or 0.7 V), and reverse current is 0 A.

A somewhat more realistic diode model uses the Shockley diode equation

$$I_d(V) = I_s \exp\left(\frac{qV}{nkT}-1\right)$$

where \$I_d(V)\$ is the current through the diode, \$I_s\$ and \$n\$ are characteristics of the device, \$k\$ is the Boltzmann constant, and \$T\$ is the junction temperature.

This gives a more accurate model of the diode behavior, but obviously would require a lot more work to actually solve a circuit with a diode in it.

An even more accurate diode model might include parasitic series and shunt resistances, reverse breakdown behavior, and other non-idealities.

> when another says "Assume non-ideal diode with VD = 0.7 V" how will the solution differ?

This wouldn't make sense, because a realistic diode model doesn't have a fixed forward voltage. You'd have to say something like, "a diode modeled by the Shockley equation with \$I_s = 2.5\times 10^{-15} {\rm A}\$, \$n=1.25\$, and operating at 273 K" or something like that.